# redux-saga how to listen to multiple eventChannel

Tags: redux-saga

I'm subscribing to 2 channels for a chat room. The code will stuck at `C` until the 2nd channel receives a new message. And then stuck at `A` until the 1st channel receives a new message.

How can I make the 2 channel working separatedly.

```
function* ChatRoomPageEnter() {
  const chanChat = yield call($stomp.eventChannel, 'ChatRoomPage', '/topic/chat');
  const chanEcho = yield call($stomp.eventChannel, 'ChatRoomPage', '/user/queue/echo');

  while (true) { // eslint-disable-line no-constant-condition
    console.log('A');
    const messageChat = yield take(chanChat);
    console.log('B');
    yield put({ type: 'chatroom/newMessage', payload: messageChat });
    console.log('C'); // <----
    const messageEcho = yield take(chanEcho);
    console.log('D');
    yield put({ type: 'chatroom/newMessage', payload: messageEcho });
    console.log('E');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a watcher as a separate function and call it twice. For example:

```
function * chatWatcher(chanName) {
  while(true) {
    const message = yield take(chanName);
    yield put({ type: 'chatroom/newMessage', payload: message });
  }
}

function* ChatRoomPageEnter() {
  const chanChat = yield call($stomp.eventChannel, 'ChatRoomPage', '/topic/chat');
  const chanEcho = yield call($stomp.eventChannel, 'ChatRoomPage', '/user/queue/echo');

  yield * chatWatcher(chanChat);
  yield * chatWatcher(chanEcho);
}
```

Comment: Instead of sequencing with yield*, I needed to use yield all([call,call]) wince I needed them to fire all in parallel, regardless this breakdown works.

Comment: You could use the third channel and put in it all events from those two channels and listen to that one to get combined data